# Odd margins on SVG Element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple SVG element with height and width equal to `80%`. I am also applying a margin of `10%` to the element to center the SVG on the page. However, for some odd reason, the margin seems to be creating a `y-overflow` so that the page is scrollable. This doesn't make much sense as I am applying styles that should add up to no more than `100%` vertically and horizontally. Here's my code:

```css
html, body {height: 100%;}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  margin: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background: #ddd;
}

svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <path d="M15,5 l10,0 l0,10 l10,0 l0,10 l-10,0 l0,10 l-10,0 l0,-10 l-10,0 l0,-10 l10,0 l0,-10 Z" />
</svg>
```

Essentially, I want the SVG to be centered with percent margins, and I don't want the body to be scrollable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [definition of `margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height). Percentage margins are calculated relative to the **width** of the containing block.

So you are setting the top and bottom margins too large. Hence the scrolling.

**Solution**

Vertically centering an element of unknown size is quite tricky. CSS does not make it easy.  But there is a little trick you can use [as explained here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

The idea is to use a second element that is 100% height, then vertically center both elements, so that the smaller one (the SVG in our case) becomes centred.

```css
html, body {height: 100%;}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background: #ddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: '\200B'; /* zero width space */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <path d="M15,5 l10,0 l0,10 l10,0 l0,10 l-10,0 l0,10 l-10,0 l0,-10 l-10,0 l0,-10 l10,0 l0,-10 Z" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y:hidden` to body to prevent it from scrolling. Here is the code snippet below.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  margin: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background: #ddd;
  top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
}

svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <path d="M15,5 l10,0 l0,10 l10,0 l0,10 l-10,0 l0,10 l-10,0 l0,-10 l-10,0 l0,-10 l10,0 l0,-10 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! But, that doesn't help because I want the element to be centered.

Comment: Can you use absolute positioning? I have edited the snippet above with absolute positioning.

Comment: Yeah, I think there are several ways I could do this. But, I more want to understand why this particular method isn't working.

Comment: It is not that percentage margin is not working. But because the height of body can be more than screen height, it adds scrolling. If you remove scrolling, then it might happen that svg may get clipped from screen view.